# Windows: Automounter daemon for NFS?

Tags: windows, nfs, automount

Unix has autofs for automounting NFS. I find it wonderful to be able to:

```
cd /nfs/my.nfsserver.example.org/exporteddir/mydir
```

and have autofs lookup the DNS name my.nfsserver.example.org, mount exporteddir automatically, and unmount again when the dir is not in use. But this only works on my Unix-machines.

Does an NFS-automounter exist for Windows (7 or 8)? So I can do something similar to:

```
cd \\nfs\my.nfsserver.example.org\exporteddir\mydir
```

Comment: Have you tried just mapping a drive letter to the NFS share?

Comment: Mapping requires free drive letters (yes: We have a complex system with > 26 exported dirs) and is not done automatically. These are two of the things I want to avoid.

Comment: True, the initial mapping is manual, but can be persistent so it's done automatically after the initial mapping, and can also be scripted.  But yes, the number of exports would certainly get in the way.

Comment: One of the problems is that which mounts are needed on the server changes dynamically, so we cannot know in advance which mounts will be needed. Currently we do that by best guessing, but we fail at that, and it is clear that if we had an automounter it would solve our issues.